# node.js 8080 port isn't listening

Tags: node.js

I'm following the node.js tutorial in here,

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/

this is the code,

```
var sys = require("sys"),  
http = require("http");  

 http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
response.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
response.write("Hello World!");  
response.close();  
 }).listen(8080);  

 sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
```

in here, it says run like this url,

server's ip:8080/

but if i do this,

it just shows, cannot connect to this url.

i opened 8080 port in the server.

===========================

I'm assuming something is screwed up with codeigniter url helper...

Comment: Please provide the information that ..... R u running your server on local machine or on the Webserver ...

Comment: What does node report?  You probably see something like `TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'sendHeader'`, which tells you that sendHeader is wrong.  You should use writeHead instead

Comment: Devrath //  it is a webserver

Comment: Nirk // i don't have any error. it says cannot connect to hosturl:8080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial may be using an incorrect or deprecated method. Replace

```
response.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
```

with

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
```

and

```
response.close();
```

with

```
response.end();
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed it. but I don't think this is my only problem :(

Answer (score 2):

**I Agree with the answer of Third .... make those changes and if it is local use this URL**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

**But**

*If you are running your server not on localmachine but on something like `webserver(AWS)`, You have to let the security of AWS firewall to allow the port to be public on the internet and also remember to use the AWS instance URL*

```
http://AWSinstanceURL:portno/
```

Comment: I'm sure you just had a typo and meant `http://127.0.0.1:8080` for accessing the server locally.

Comment: i'm assuming this is the firewall rule issue. if i type iptables -L it says target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache

Comment: doesn't this mean accept everything? i don't know why it is not working. ofcourse i added 8080 port accept to the iptables and restart

Comment: @ user1765884 ...... Its very simple but tricky one ..... Each web server has a feature called firewall you have to tell the web-server to allow the port that you are accessing public via internet ...... Ex:: I use AWS web-server and its instance have a feature called security group to make port public ...... My suggestion is you Check your web-server control pannel to access its firewall ...... **If you feel my answer is correct ... mark it as accept & upvote it** .. _If you have problems still reply back & i will try to guide you solve it_ hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Now open http://localhost:8080  and u will get your result.